# I would like some advice why this would not insert data into my SQL table

Tags: python, sql, text-files

Following is my code:

```
import MySQLdb
def insert_popularity(PersonNumber, Category, Value):

# make a connection to the dataabse
connection = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', user='root', \
                             passwd='password', db='inb104')

# get a cursor on the database
cursor = connection.cursor()

# construct the SQL statement
sql = ("""INSERT INTO popularity (PersonNumber, Category, Value)
        VALUES(%s, %s, %s)""", (number, category, data))

def open_file(filename):        
    txt_file = file(filename, 'r')
    for line in txt_file:
        # Split the line on whitespace
        for value in line.split():                
            return value

            number = value[0]
            data = value[1]

# execute the query
cursor.execute(sql)

# commit the changes to the database\
connection.commit()

# close the cursor and connection
cursor.close()

connection.close()
```

**Update:**

After changing my code as per [Paulo's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6148293/i-would-like-some-advice-why-this-would-not-insert-data-into-my-sql-table/6148365#6148365) I now get this error:

```
query() argument 1 must be string or read-only buffer, not tuple.
```

I am not sure what it is after trying to change my code:

```
def insert_popularity(Category, filename, cursor):

    txt_file = file(filename, 'r')
    for line in txt_file:
            # Split the line on whitespace
        number, value = line.split()
            # construct the SQL statement
        sql = ("""INSERT INTO popularity (PersonNumber, Category, Value)
                VALUES(%s, %s, %s)""", (number, Category, value))
            # execute the query
        cursor.execute(sql)

connection = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', user='root', \
                                 passwd='password', db='dogs')

cursor = connection.cursor()

Category = 'dogs'
insert_popularity(Category, 'dogs.txt', cursor)
connection.commit()
cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

Comment: What happened? Did you get an error message?

Comment: no error message just when i look in the database there is no data

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error in SQLite query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6148987/error-in-sqlite-query)

Answer (score 2):

You've created the query to execute as a tuple. There two possibilities to solve this:

1. Use the created query (sql) as a list of arguments:

   `sql = ("""INSERT INTO popularity (PersonNumber, Category, Value)
           VALUES(%s, %s, %s)""", (number, Category, value))
       # execute the query
   cursor.execute(*sql)`
2. Directly add the query to the execute method:

   `cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO popularity (PersonNumber, Category, Value)
           VALUES(%s, %s, %s)""", (number, Category, value))`

Number 2 is definitely a better option than the first one. Thanks to all comments!

Comment: -1 on your first possibility because (1) `sql` applied to a tuple is a misnomer (2) it's byzantine putting a *known* number of args into a tuple (`sql`) and then immediately calling a method with *sql (3) you haven't read your answer (it needs two line breaks)

Comment: could you please re word that im not sure what you mean?

Comment: @Ryan: If your request is addressed to me: "Do not use Thijs's first 'possibility'."

Answer (score 2):

Just do it simply, one thing at a time, no fancy stuff that is error prone and slows the reader down while they navigate the obfuscation:

```
sql = """INSERT INTO popularity (PersonNumber, Category, Value) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"""
args = (number, Category, value)
cursor.execute(sql, args)
```

Your comment (execute the query) went away because (a) it was wrong (insert != query) and (b) the fixed version (execute the insertion) would be quite redundant given the clarity of the fixed code.

**Update** after new problem (too many values to unpack):

Instead of this code:

```
for line in txt_file:
        # Split the line on whitespace
    number, value = line.split()
```

do this:

```
for lino, line in enumerate(txt_file, 1):
    pieces = line.split()
    if len(pieces) != 2:
        print "Bad data in line %d: %r" % (lino, pieces)
        continue
    number, value = pieces
```

Comment: thanks for that. but now it is saying that there are too many values to unpack when im spliting the line. how would i shorten that?

Comment: @ryan: Fix your data; you are expecting two pieces of whitespace-separated data per line, but at least one line has 3 or more such pieces.

Comment: is threre a way to slip at the first whitespace so all the following data would go into the value variable?

Comment: @ John: it says enumerate() takes exactly 1 argument and 2 are given

Comment: @Ryan: Hard to tell what you fixed. Stop after 1st whitespace: `line.split(None, 1)`. enumerate problem: You are using Python 2.5 or earlier. If you can't upgrade (to 2.7), write code to count lines yourself -- you'll still a line number to report other problems :)

Answer (score 1):

What are the data types of the number, category, and data?  If any of these are strings, then you should wrap them in single quotes in your query.

Comment: number is an int and catgory and data are strings

Comment: The good database libraries will handle the proper quoting of variables based on type.

Answer (score 1):

Do not take me wrong, but the code is very messed up...

1. the return inside the for loop will return the first splited string in the first line.
2. open_file is defined but never called

and so on...

My take would be something like:

```
def process_file(category, filename, cursor):
    txt_file = file(filename, 'r')
    for line in txt_file:
        number, value = line.split()
        sql = ("""INSERT INTO popularity (PersonNumber, Category, Value)
            VALUES(%s, %s, %s)""", (number, category, data))
        cursor.execute(sql)

connection = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', user='root',
                         passwd='password', db='inb104')
# get a cursor on the database
cursor = connection.cursor()
category = 'foo'
process_file(category, 'somefile.txt', cursor)
# commit the changes to the database\
connection.commit()
# close the cursor and connection
cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

Comment: haha yeah sorry im very new to programing... its ok i will just try to make it work somehow

Comment: ahh so are you ment to execute the sql statement within the function?

Comment: Python is a great first language. Try to finish the tutorial at http://docs.python.org/tutorial/, it really pays up!

Comment: @Ree, if you intend to insert a record for each line in the file then yes, you have to execute the insert inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
def insert_popularity(Category, filename, cursor):
    sql = """INSERT INTO popularity (PersonNumber, Category, Value)
           VALUES(%s, %s, %s)"""

    txt_file = file(filename, 'r')
    for line in txt_file:
        # Split the line on whitespace
        number, value = line.split()
        # execute the query
        cursor.execute(sql, (number, Category, value))
    txt_file.close()

connection = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', user='root', \
                                 passwd='password', db='dogs')

cursor = connection.cursor()

Category = 'dogs'
insert_popularity(Category, 'dogs.txt', cursor)

connection.commit()
cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

Also note: your code suggests this is a MySQL database; if it's an SQLite database, like the title of your question says, please substitute `'?'` for every `'%s'` in the sql statement.